# Testing objects that are usually generated by factories with phpspec

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpspec

How do you go about implementing tests that can leverage your factories to create your test objects?

For example, imagine you have a Zend Framework 2 factory like so:

```
class FooServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface{

    public function createService( ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator ){

        $bar = new Bar($serviceLocator->get('config'));
        return new FooService( $bar );
    }
}
```

I could easily modify my FooServiceSpec's let function to look like this (using [my ZF2 phpspec extension to get the SM](https://github.com/Saeven/phpspec-zf2)):

```
function let(){
    $bar = new Bar($this->getServiceLocator()->get('config'));
    $this->beConstructedWith( $bar );
}
```

In doing so, however, I am not testing my factories.  I could of course write separate tests to test the factories themselves, but it's a duplicated effort.

Is there a means to completely defer object instantiation to a custom routine?  That way in my test, I could do (fictitious):

```
function letBetter(){
    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get(FooService::class);
}
```

Trying avoid duplication!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing your `FooService` object, you should only test the `FooService` object and mock everything else (you shouldn't use any service locator unit in the spec):

```php
class FooServiceSpec extends ObjectBehaviour
{
    function let(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($bar);
    }

    function it_xxx()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to test the factory, test the factory only and not the service locator or `FooService`.

Comment: Furthermore, you should write a separate integration test for your factory to make sure that it actually does what it promises and creates a FooService. You wouldn't use phpspec for this, but for example phpunit.